# Clash of Clans Bases and Game Center Accounts

Tags: data-synchronization, game-center, clash-of-clans

About a month ago I bought a new iPhone. Previously, I had been playing Clash of Clans on another device on one Game Center account. When I bought the iPhone, I set up another Game Center account. I would like to sync my base from the old account to the new account so I can play on my iPhone.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use your old Game Center account for your new device too.
Or you can follow the guide here: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Center_User_Guide

Answer (score 0):

On your new clash account play through the tutorial and make sure you don't upgrade the th or make any purchases.

After that you can go into settings and link your new device!.

Answer (score -2):

Link a device. Settings/device/link device . Then you do the rest. Hope this helps